# Относится ли точка к треугольнику? С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

препод по информатике задал мне определить принадлежит ли точка M(x,y) области, внешней по отношению к треугольнику с вершинами A(a,0), B(b,0), C(0,c), где a b и c - положительные числа, причем b>a, одну программу я сделал, но он ее забраковал, потому что он не понял формулы которые там были использованы, я, если честно, тоже не понял что это за формулы. Также ему не понравилось что когда точка находится на границе треугольника программа выводит, что точка принадлежит треугольнику. А не "точка находится на ребре" или подобное.

```css
int main()
{
float x,y,a,b,c;
cout<<"Enter a,b,c \n";
cin>>a;
cin>>b;
cin>>c;
cout<<"Enter x and y \n";
cin>>x;
cin>>y;
if (b<c)
  {
       if ( (y>=(a-a*x/b)) && (y>=0) && (y<=(a-a*x/c)))
         { cout<<"prinadlezhyt";}
            else cout<<"ne prinadlezhyt";
   }
else
  cout<< " b>c \n";
}
```

Comment: *он не понял формулы которые там были использованы, я, если честно, тоже не понял что это за формулы* А откуда они вообще взялись, формулы-то?

Comment: Вершины треугольника и заданная точка образуют 4 возможных треугольника. По координатам считаешь их площади (формула Герона). Если две площади нулевые - точка есть одна из вершин, если одна нулевая - точка лежит на стороне, если площадь заданного треугольника равна сумме площадей остальных - точка внутри, иначе снаружи.

Comment: Формулы были взяты из первой ссылки в выдаче гугла)

Comment: С учётом ограничений есть ещё один вариант. Проведи прямую через С и заданную точку, да найди пересечение с осью абсцисс (если таковой нет, прямая горизонтальна, проверить, не равен ли х нулю). Если она между А и В, то точка внутри, если совпадает с А или В, то на стороне, иначе снаружи. Ну и конечно х должен быть положителен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно нарисовать треугольник при заданных условиях и посмотреть, как он выглядит.
Условие `(y>0)` понятное. Две наклонные линии, пересекающие оси в указанных точках, дают уравнения прямых "в отрезках"

```
x/a + y/c = 1
x/b + y/c = 1
```

Для первого уравнения для точек выше прямой

```
y/c > 1 - x/a или
y > с - с*x/a
```

Для второго для точек ниже прямой

```
y/c < 1 - x/b или
y < с - с*x/b
```

Вот и все условия. На ваши похожи, однако вы их написали, не применив правильно к данным конкретной задачи

Comment: Достаточно одной любой точке быть (0,0), чтобы всё рассыпалось... домножить бы всё на (b*c).

Comment: Так условие же, что числа положительные. Так-то и в знаках я полагаюсь, что b>a обязательно

Comment: Ох, не верю я всем этим условиям... любимая фишка препода - "а чё будет, ежли мы вот енто ограниченьице похерим, а?".

Comment: Домножить-то можно, не доверяя,  но тогда и знак может быть другой, и неравенства обратиться

Comment: С чего бы это знаку поменяться, при домножении на положительные числа-то?

Comment: Не верим в не ноль - почему тогда про положительные верим?

Comment: Ааа... ну тады да.

Comment: Так а все-таки дорогие друзья, как сделать так, чтобы программа выводила что точка находится на границе треугольника или на вершине, попытался сделать по формуле герона, не очень получилось :(

Comment: Ох, я перечитал вопрос, и увидел там `внешней по отношению к треугольнику`, а я условия привёл для внутренней области. Для отдельной проверки на границу надо проверять равенства.